# Can´t execute jSoup Parser

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have been looking for information in order to use jSoup so that I can extract some elements from another website, but I can't make it run.

I have installed Java and Maven, I created a Java file and then a pom.xml dependency, but when I execute it on Terminal (I'm using Mac), it gives me errors.

[image: errors]

I'm totally lost. I can't even run a simple code so that I can start understanding. I have make several google search but all the tutorials start over a basic knowledge.

I would appreciate if you could tell me where could I start from 0 knowledge, because I´m getting desperate.

Comment: is you who created the POM.xml?

Comment: Yes, I create with just one <dependency>, but to be honest I don´t really understand what I am doing. I know that pom.xml is so important, but as all the tutorials I have seen the use an specific one...I don´t know how many possibilities exist.

Comment: pom is generated automatically it's not you who create it, use the wizard and choose create a new maven project not java project

Comment: @KhalilM I didn´t know that. I´m sorry but in this topic I missunterstand many things, I am spanish and technical vocabulary makes me lost. As I know I can create a Maven project with Eclipse. I will try then...

Comment: dont be, after you create it you ll find the pom.xml already so add your dependencies there

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't need maven in order to run JSoup, you can:

1. download the `jsoup jar` from [jsoup.org](https://jsoup.org/download),
2. put it to the project classpath (eg. [add jar to netbeans project](http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-netbeans/))
3. import `jsoup` in your class

and you're good to go.

#### with maven

1. create a Maven project (eg [maven-quickstart](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html)) the process could be slightly different depending on the IDE that you're using.
2. add the jsoup dependencies to the pom, by either following the instruction in the link above, or editing the `POM.xml`, so it looks :

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.yourorgaaniztion</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup-with-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

the project structure (pom.xml location) should looks like:
[image]

> I would appreciate if you could tell me where could I star from 0 knowledge, >because I´m getting desperate.

from this point, I think you could continue with [this mkyong tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/)

Comment: he can also use maven to get jsoup if he wants

Comment: indeed, i'll add the correct POM, after I'll check a local project :)

Comment: but it's not that the question

Comment: by checking the log in his image, it seems that his issue is that `there is no POM in his directory`, so either it's not created or not maven not configured/used properly.. .

Comment: Just to clarify, the POM in created my self, but it´s inside some folders, so I don´t know if it not reading because it is not well configured or because I haven´t specified the folder exactly. But I have tried and I can´t.

In Terminal y write "cd downloads" to enter to download folder because is there where I have and then:

1.- "javac thenameofthefile.java"
2.- "java thenameofthefile"

Just to compile it, but when I execute the second step all the errors are shown.

Comment: what IDE you're using ?

Comment: @yaitloutou 

First of all, thanks for your time. I don´t know what IDE really means, but I think that you refer the program I use to edit code? if is that I am using Atom. About Maven I have installed it using terminal, but I haven´t downloaded any software for it. 

The folders structures have to be the way you have listed? I mean, does it matter if I introduce de pom.xml file inside another folder or it works like the stylesheet in html? 

I keep having troubles, but as I said among the missunterstandin things and that I haven´t got much idea...

Comment: you are correct, I was referring to `the integrated development environment (IDE)`, while you can create definitively code `Atom` or `Sublime Text`  or even a blocnote there are just text-editors, so the pom.xml will not be created automatically. and there are many other missing feature. there for suggest that you use a proper java IDE like [eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) or [netbeans](https://netbeans.org) they are free and open-source. and the installation takes just some minutes.

Comment: for the other question, **yes** you most have the seem structure. and since you are new with java, I guess, you'd be better to go without maven following my first suggestion. so you'll have less stuff to worry about. and you can create a java scrapper more quickly.

Comment: if you have a javascript background, I'd say that `maven` is the same as `npm` a dependencies manager, so the `pom.xml` whould be the equivalent of `package.json`, hence it needs to be created and structured in a specific way, and placed in the root of the project (not inside any folder).<br/>
but the point is **you want to scrap some data using java+jsoup**  and some limited java knowledge. then, since the 2 are enough to get the job down, way border your self with additional stuff right now?!

Comment: @yaitloutou I have been watching a video where it is explained how to create a Maven project, but I don´t know why it keeps showing me "fail". 

Now I´m understanding better. The POM is automatically generated. But I would like to understand how does this program really work.

I want to scrap xbox.com page and export those scrapped elements to an excel, and then to a database. It´s harder than I thought...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @yaitloutou, I really appreciate it. I would like to talk about this but I want also to see if I can find de problem I´m having, anyway here in Spain is 3 a.m so I should be sleeping. Thanks again!

Comment: you welcome. btw, if it's about the website in your profile, you can scrap all the data that you need with some JSoup's `http request` . but if you're dealing with website that load some ajax and jquery content, you may need to use additional tools like `HTMLUnit`..  have a good night, and good scrapping :D

Answer (score 0):

The pom.xml file describes your project so that Maven knows how to compile it. At a minimum you need to define your project's group ID, artifact ID, and version--the Maven "coordinates." If your project requires libraries, like jsoup, then you can include a <dependencies> section with a <dependency> for each library. I think you've gotten this far.

Maven expects the project to have a certain structure.

- You should have a directory with the pom.xml in it.
- You should have a subdirectory called "src"
- Within the "src" directory, you should have a directory called "main"
- Within "main," you should have a subdirectory called "java"
- Within "java," Java source files live in directories that correspond to their packages, so if you have "package com.manuelsagra.laxtore" for class App then that goes in (the directory with pom.xml)/src/main/java/com/manuelsagra/laxtore/App.java.

Sorry if some of this is review for you.

You should run Maven (mvn) from the top directory containing pom.xml:

```
$ mvn install
```

That should download jsoup and compile anything in src/main/java.

Then you can run "mvn exec:java ..." from the same directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I unsderstand way better how it works, but I keep having problems. I'm following an example [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/) with no result, all errors. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong...

Following another example i get the right code:

[link](http://jarroba.com/maven-en-eclipse/). 

I would like to scrap and then create and excel with that information. 

Thanks!